# UICollectionView not showing selected data after long scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have one `UICollectionView` with five custom cells that need to be render on specific conditions, cells are getting generated. Now problem I am going through is consider I have selected one cell at specific index, and now I scroll downwards and now again I long scroll. When `UICollectionView` stops scrolling, if the index is the same as which we selected, `UICollectionView` doesn't show that cell as selected. But now if I even try to move the cell a little bit, even a bit, `UICollectionView` shows that cell as selected cell. 
Following is my code, that I have wrote in **prefetchItem**:

```
(cell as? PATemplateTypeOneCollectionCell)?.fillCellData(row: indexPath.row,section:indexPath.section, paCategoryQuestions: currentIndexQuestion, paQuestionCollection: currentIndexCollection)
                    cell!.alpha = 0.4
                    if self.multipleIndexPathsArray[indexPath.section][0] != []{                         
                        collectionView.selectItem(at: self.multipleIndexPathsArray[indexPath.section][0], animated: true, scrollPosition: .right)
                    }
                    else{
                        print("self.multipleIndexPathsArray[indexPath.section][0] is empty")
                    }
```

UICollectionViewCell:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
didSet {
    if isSelected {
        self.alpha = 1.0
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        self.layer.borderColor = ColorConstants.colorFromHexString(hexString: paCategoryQuestions.selection_color).cgColor
    }else {
        self.alpha = 0.4
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    }
}
```

Kindly request you guys to help with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours of thinking I came across one solution. So as my cellForItem was not rendering selected scroll properly after long scroll, what I tried is recognizing `UIScrollView`'s delegate `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`. And recognizing if currently visible indexPath cells were selected previously or not by using my saved values array. Following is the code that worked for me:

```
fileprivate func checkIfCellIsSelected(){
    for eachCell in afterPaymentPACollectionView.visibleCells{
        let indexPath = afterPaymentPACollectionView.indexPath(for: eachCell)
        for eachIndexSelected in multipleIndexPathsArray{
            if eachIndexSelected.contains(indexPath!){
                afterPaymentPACollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .right)
            }
        }  
    }
}

//MARK: UIScrollViewDelegate
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    checkIfCellIsSelected()

}
```